# File picker type image returns null flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image, mobile, filepicker

I have a problem with file picker type image.
when I specify the type of the file as image file the function returns null , but when I specify an other type ,it returns the path file.

**File picker without type :**
**- code :**

> 

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
if (result != null) {
  PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
  print(file.name);
  print(file.bytes);
  print(file.size);
  print(file.extension);
  print(file.path);
} else {
  print("null);
}
```

**return**
imagepath : /data/user/0/com.tanitweb.divadeep/cache/file_picker/images.jpeg

And when add type of file in the same code it returns null

**File picker withtype :**

```
> FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);
if (result != null) {
  PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
  print(file.name);
  print(file.bytes);
  print(file.size);
  print(file.extension);
  print(file.path);
} else {
  print("null);
}
```

**return**
null

Comment: i got same result, no solution yet?

Comment: I was using android:launchMode="singleInstance" in my manifest file , and when I changed it to android:launchMode="singleTop" it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is simple, just add: withData: true

```
FilePickerResult? result;

result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
 type: FileType.image,
 withData: true
 );
```

Answer (score -3):

Add the below line on **project root/ios/Podfile** before the line target `'Runner' do.`

```
Pod::PICKER_MEDIA = false, 
Pod::PICKER_AUDIO = false, 
Pod::PICKER_DOCUMENT = false
```

After added, the code should look like this

```
Pod::PICKER_MEDIA = false, resp. Pod::PICKER_AUDIO = false, resp. Pod::PICKER_DOCUMENT = false
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
```

Comment: This gives me `Invalid Podfile file: undefined local variable or method resp`. This seems copy-and-pasted straight from the [iOS Setup instructions](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Setup/) without any testing. What works for me is putting `Pod::PICKER_MEDIA = false` on one line, then `Pod::PICKER_AUDIO = false` on the next, then `Pod::PICKER_DOCUMENT = false` on the next line.